# Under Irish law can the Gardaí give a person's statement to a 3rd party government department?

Tags: criminal-law, european-union, statement

I have an Irish law question. I have tried to get a few solicitors to answer it but they seem unable to give me a concrete answer. I'm hoping someone on here can help or point me in the right direction.

Under Irish law, can the Gardaí give a person's statement to a third party government department who are not directly involved in the ongoing case? And if they are allowed to do so, am I entitled to find out the person's name they gave it to?

The [Citizen's Information website](http://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/justice/law_and_rights/access_to_garda_records.html) states that I have a right to "Know the identity of anyone to whom the Gardaí disclose [data they hold on me]". However, on contacting the Gardaí they have told me that they do not have to disclose any names of individuals they have given the statement to.

Any help would be appreciated.